# Sitespeed.io and graphite

Tags: node.js, system, graphite, system-administration

I m actually trying to use sitespeed.io and graphite together and I m facing a problem.

In fact, I want to use this commande line :

```
 sitespeed.io -u http://google.com -b firefox --graphiteHost http://127.0.0.1:3000 --graphiteNamespace sitespeed.io.newyork
```

and here's the error that I get :

```
error: Error getting versions: { [Error: Command failed: /home/skahrz/.nvm/v0.11.16/lib/node_modules/sitespeed.io/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --version
/home/skahrz/.nvm/v0.11.16/lib/node_modules/sitespeed.io/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
]
  killed: false,
  code: 127,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/home/skahrz/.nvm/v0.11.16/lib/node_modules/sitespeed.io/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --version' }
error:  Error: Command failed: /home/skahrz/.nvm/v0.11.16/lib/node_modules/sitespeed.io/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --version
/home/skahrz/.nvm/v0.11.16/lib/node_modules/sitespeed.io/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:744:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)
```

I dont know how to work through this and to well generate my sitespeed report.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If graphite is running on same host or different host doesnt matter- but carbon will be listening on 2003 and not 3000... 3000 is grafana default port.

you cannot pass the port like a normal url... if u want to pass graphite port to sitespeed... use --graphitePort 2003 or wherever your carbon is listening.